# Construct a matrix in Matlab where each element is obtained by summing all other elements in the same row

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `A` of zeros and ones in Matlab of dimension `MxN`. I want to construct a matrix `B` of dimension `MxN`, where `B(i,j)` is obtained by summing  `A(h,j)` for all `h` different from `i`.

This is my current code

```
A=randi([0 1],2097144,20); %2097144x20
B = @( )bsxfun(@minus,sum(A(:,2:end),2),A(:,2:end)); %2097144x20
timeit(B)
```

which takes approx. 0.5 sec.

Would you be able to suggest anything faster?

---

**Edited question thanks to the comments below:** the code is correct; my explanation to it is wrong; the correct explanation is

I have a matrix `A` of zeros and ones in Matlab of dimension `MxN`. I want to construct a matrix `B` of dimension `MxN`, where `B(i,j)` is obtained by summing  `A(i,h)` for all `h` different from `j`.

Comment: That's about as fast as you're going to get it. If you're using R2016b or newer you could reduce it to `sum(A(:,2:end)) - A(:,2:end)`

Comment: In native MATLAB code, that will be at the plateau in terms of efficiently computing what you're asking.  If you really want to push it faster, you may consider writing MEX code but that's a lot more effort than it's worth as you're already doing this as fast as possible without MEX.

Comment: Thank you both. I am struggling with @bsxfun. Probably I don't know how to use it properly, but it is always somehow involved in the slowest parts of my code. I have asked another question about it today.

Comment: Your code does not do exactly what you describe. Why `2:end`?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. The code is correct; the explanation is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to call the code a large number of times. If you want to call it with many *different* matrices A, then as far as I can see, you are more or less out of luck - mex can help you somewhat - you may be able to speed it up by say a factor of 2 or 3 but you are basically memory bound.

If on the other hand you are doing something more subtle, then it depends on the specific problem at hand - perhaps you can use the parallel toolbox or the gpu.

Answer (score -1):

You code doesn't do what you have stated. You wanted to sum along the columns (across rows that is). Moreover, why have you skipped the first column. As per your requirement, the correct line would be

```
B = bsxfun(@minus,sum(A,1),A);
```

which is about 4 times as fast.

Comment: That is not what I want. For example if `A=[1 1; 1 0; 0 1; 0 0]`, then `B=[1 1; 0 1; 1 0; 0 0]`. Your code gives me  `C=[1 1; 1 2; 2 1; 2 2]`

Comment: As stated in my question: I want to construct a matrix `B` of dimension `MxN`, where `B(i,j)` is obtained by summing  `A(h,j)` for all `h` different from `i`

Comment: I don't understand. If B(i,j) = sum of A(h,j) over h ~= i, then for example B(2,1) should be sum of A(h,1) over h ~= 2 which is:

    A(1,1) + A(3,1) + A(4,1)

which should be 1 (as in C) and not 0 (as in B).

Comment: Apologies, my mistake! The code is right, what I wrote to explain it is wrong!!